# Normal subgroups and quotients

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H,K\unlhd G$ with $K\le H$. How can I prove that $\frac{H}{K} \unlhd \frac{G}{K}$ ?
I tried to start with the definition of normal subgroup: let $hK\in \frac{H}{K}$ and $gK\in \frac{G}{K}$, $(gK)^{-1}(hK)(gK)=(g^{-1}K)(hK)(gK)=(g^{-1}hg)K\in\frac{H}{K}$. Does this prove the lemma?

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: You should also supply the argument why $g^{-1}hg\in H$ and then the proof should be complete.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for the advice

Comment: An alternative way to do this is to define a homomorphism with domain $G/K$ whose kernel is $H/K$. For example, you can start by mapping $G$ to some group in a way that you can guarantee the kernel contains $K$ to get an induced homomorphism from $G/K$, and go from there.